# "Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless DeleteCommand is specified" Yet deletion still happens

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a project for asp.net, and added my code for deleting a record. However when I run it I get the error

> Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless
>   DeleteCommand is specified.

Extensive googling has not yielded a sufficient answer. Also when I check my SQL tables the delete command has successfully removed the entry, and yet still I get this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
    Dim thisID As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    ' Get the id - Cell(0) is the first column in the grid
    ' If you have the delete or edit links on the left this column will change!
    thisID = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Text
    ' Delete the specific record
    ' Use hard-coded values first to check your work
    ' strSQL = "DELETE FROM userTable WHERE id = 25"
    strSQL = "DELETE FROM " & TABLE_NAME & " WHERE Name = '" & thisID & "'"
    runNonSelect(strSQL)
    RefreshGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to add the following to your question by [edit]ing it: (1) the `runNonSelect` subroutine code and (2) the code used to create/assign the data source for your grid view. It would seem they are relevant to the error you are observing.

Comment: Most likely it's because the grid will call delete on your SqlDataSource, but you are using some other custom method for deleting, which will be called first, then the grid will attempt to call delete on your sqldatasource which you haven't done anything with. Bottom line, you're deleting but not using the grid and sqldatasource properly